# Pegar dados de uma tabela dinâmica e salvar no mysql

Tags: php, javascript, mysql, ajax

boa noite.
Faz tempo que não programo! Estou enferrujado, rsrs

Preciso de ajuda. Estou fazendo um sistema para controlar orçamentos.

o meu problema é que preciso pegar essas informações de produtos e jogar em uma tabela do mysql(tb_orcamentos). Eu não sei como devo fazer isso. =\

segue foto: [image: criação de pedido de compra]

**Código para exibir os campos do form:**

```html
<tr class='tr_input'>
                <form method="post" action="cad-novo-pdc.php">
                    <td><center><input type='text' class='username' id='username_1' name="username_1" placeholder='Informe o produto'></center></td>
                    <td><center><input type='text' class='id' id='id_1' name="id_1" readonly></center></td>
                    <td><center><input type='text' class='name' id='name_1'  name="name_1" required></center></td>
                    <td><center><input type='text' class='salary' id='salary_1' name="salary_1" onKeyUp="moeda(this);" required></center></td>

                <td><center><button type="button" class="btn btn-warning" onclick="remove(this)">Excluir</button></center></td>

            </tr>
```

**Código JS para dar a funcionalidade de "adicionar item":**

```js
$('#addmore').click(function(){

                // Get last id 
                var lastname_id = $('.tr_input input[type=text]:nth-child(1)').last().attr('id');
                var split_id = lastname_id.split('_');

                // New index
                var index = Number(split_id[1]) + 1;

                // Create row with input elements
                var html = "<tr class='tr_input'>\n\
                            <td><center><input type='text' class='username' id='username_"+index+"' placeholder='Informe o produto'></center></td>\n\
                            <td><center><input type='text' class='id_' id='id_"+index+"' readonly></center></td>\n\
                            <td><center><input type='text' class='name' id='name_"+index+"' ></center></td>\n\
                            <td><center><input type='text' class='salary' id='salary_"+index+"' onKeyUp='moeda(this);'  ></center></td>\n\
                            <td><center><button type='button' class='btn btn-warning' onclick='remove(this)'>Excluir</button></td></center></tr>";

                // Append data
                $('tbody').append(html);

            });
```

eu criei um método post no form, mas ele só envia a primeira linha de produto inserida. Agora, não sei o que fazer para pegar um ou 50 itens que forem digitados no orçamento. Conseguem me dar uma ajuda? xD

**A função de gravar deve entrar em ação quando se clicar no botão "finalizar pedido".**

Realmente estou a mais de 5 anos sem pegar em um code =\

saudações a todos \o/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Está faltando apenas adicionar o atributo `name` nos campos gerados dinamicamente pelo seu código JS. Para resolver, adicione o atributo `name` nos campos gerados via javascript.

**Exemplo:** ao lado de `id='username_"+index+"'`, adicione `name='username_"+index+"'`, e assim por diante para todos os 4 campos.

**Explicação:** Sem o atributo `name`, o campo do formulário não é enviado via POST pelo navegador. E é por isso que só a primeira linha está sendo enviada, pois no HTML fixado para o item 1 você colocou o `name` corretamente. O problema está só na parte dinâmica (linha 2 em diante).

Depois que você tiver feito isso, conseguirá acessar todas as variáveis via POST por meio do PHP. Para testar que todos os valores estão chegando corretamente, substitua o conteúdo do arquivo **cad-novo-pdc.php**, provisoriamente, por `<?php var_dump($_POST); ?>` e submeta o formulário.

Comment: não funcionou meu amigo.

Comment: Para te ajudar a debuggar, faça o seguinte: inspecione os campos gerados dinamicamente (utilizando a ferramenta DevTools do navegador Google Chrome, por exemplo, apertando a tecla F12 do navegador), e veja se os campos da 2ª linha garanham os ids e names corretos.

Comment: Outro problema que eu identifiquei: a sua tag `<form>` está dentro da tag `<tr>`. Para que todas as informações sejam submetidas, o formulário deve estar por fora da `<table>`. Deve ser algo assim (apenas exemplificando a estrutura): `<form><table><tr><td></td><td></td></tr><tr><td></td><td></td></tr></table></form>`.

Comment: obrigado amigo!
a saída ficou:
`array (size=8)
  'username_1' => string 'calha dutotec' (length=13)
  'id_1' => string '2' (length=1)
  'name_1' => string '3' (length=1)
  'salary_1' => string '1000.24' (length=7)
  'username_2' => string 'fita isolante' (length=13)
  'id_2' => string '15' (length=2)
  'name_2' => string '10' (length=2)
  'salary_2' => string '17.80' (length=5)`
**porém quando coloco a pagina cad-novo-pdc exibe apenas o primeiro, exemplo de como está:**

`$razao = $_POST['username_1'];
$fantasia = $_POST['name_1'];
$endereco = $_POST['salary_1'];`

Comment: Isso que está hardcoded (username_1, etc), você vai ter que deixar dinâmico. Como o seu frontend não tem limitador de registros, você tem que fazer um loop infinito e forçar a parada quando perceber que chegou ao fim. Exemplo: <?php $i = 1; while (true) { if (!isset($_POST["username_$i"])) { break; } $razao = $_POST["username_$i"];  /* etc */ } ?>

Comment: meu amigo, muito obrigado, mas eu não consigo mais passar daqui...nao sei o que fazer. coloquei esse while que vc pediu na pagina cad-novo-pdc mas fica em loop carregando....

Comment: @RonierickHolanda vi que você é um usuário novo do StackOverflow, bem vindo! Vou te dar algumas dicas que vão ajudar você a tirar suas dúvidas. Esse é um site de perguntas e respostas diretas, objetivas, então precisamos evitar ficar conversando pelos comentários. Se estamos tendo muita conversa pelos comentários, significa que a sua pergunta está com escopo muito amplo.

Comment: Recomendo que faça o seguinte: edite a sua pergunta atual, e deixe ela bem objetiva, diminuindo o escopo. Remova a parte sobre banco de dados da pergunta. Como minha resposta já resolveu seu problema da parte que vai do frontend até o $_POST, recomendo que você marque a minha resposta como aceita, e faça outra pergunta pedindo ajuda para fazer um loop sobre os dados do $_POST. Assim, eu e outros usuários podemos te ajudar, de forma mais organizada, sobre o restante da sua dúvida. Ou seja, sempre quebre seu problema em perguntas pequenas, e vamos resolvendo uma coisa de cada vez.